# Create an order using WooCommerce API v3 in Ionic 4

Tags: api, woocommerce, e-commerce, angular7, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm creating an Hybrid Mobile App using **Angular v7** and **Ionic v4** 
 
How to create an order using Woo-commerce APIs? 
**WooCommerce** **v3** 
**WC** Version **3.5.x** 
**WordPress** Version **4.4** 
**Ionic v4** 
**Angular v7**

Using post request how we can create an new order using **WooCommmerce** in **Angular 7** & **Ionic 4**
and then clear the **Cart** after submitting order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object like this to pass in POST method

```js
createOrderData = {
    payment_method: "cod",
    payment_method_title: "Cash on delivery",
    set_paid: true,
    billing: {
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
      address_1: "969 Market",
      address_2: "",
      city: "San Francisco",
      state: "CA",
      postcode: "57000",
      country: "PK",
      email: "john.doe@example.com",
      phone: "(555) 555-5555"
    },
    shipping: {
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
      address_1: "969 Market",
      address_2: "",
      city: "San Francisco",
      state: "CA",
      postcode: "57000",
      country: "Pk"
    },
    line_items: [
      {
        product_id: 7191,
        quantity: 2
      },
      {
        product_id: 7195,
        variation_id: 23,
        quantity: 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then create an function & call this function to execute the post method

```js
addOrder() {
    this.http.post("https://www.websitename.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", this.createOrderData)
      .subscribe(
        async data => {
          console.log("Order successfully created", data);
        },
        async error => {
          console.log("Error", error);
        }
      );
  }
```